# AWS Sam build java layer and include on classpath

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-lambda-layers

I have built a lambda layer using aws sam and am including it in my lambda function.  It deploys, and shows up in the console (I have only a few lines of code in my whole application, but I can link it if you wish).

As a quick test that the layer is loaded on the classpath, I have included the layer as a compileOnly dependency in my lambda, so I can reference it at compile time.  Then in the first line of my lambda, I invoke a method on the class from the layer, and it continues to give me noclassdeffounderrors, which suggests it is not on the classpath.

Is my understanding of lambda layers correct?  Is there anything else I need to do to get the layer included on the classpath and accessible?  Would I also be able to provide runtime only dependencies using the layer?

Also, I've noticed that when I download the jar from the layer, all the files are in the root of the layer, not included in /java directory as some sam documentation suggests it should be.  Should I look at this?

Answer (score 0):

Each language supports a different path. For Java it is java/lib. It's described in the Lambda developer guide.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html